# Debian testing unable to get screen information and control brightness with Gnome 3.21.90

Tags: debian, xorg, gnome, intel, backlight

After upgrading Debian testing on Dell XPS13 (2015) yesterday, to Gnome 3.21.90, none of the Gnome applications are able to get screen information anymore, and brightness control broke (Fn+F11 and Fn+F12). See images:

[image: Screen information]
[image: System details]

This is however striking as both `xrandr` and `xorg` seem to detect the display correctly:

```
$ xradr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 290mm x 170mm

$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep backlight
gdm-Xorg-:0[791]: (--) intel(0): found backlight control interface /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight

$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep backlight
[     5.463] (--) intel(0): found backlight control interface /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
```

And brightness control works via both

```
echo x > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/backlight
```

and

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --brightness x
```

I have tried many things, booting kernel with `acpi_backlight=vendor`, `acpi_osi=`, adding an `20-intel.conf` to both the `xorg.conf.d` in `/usr/share` and `/etc`, and reinstalling all installed packages but to no avail...

**UPDATE**

The issue has indeed resolved itself after transitioning to Gnome 3.21 from the stretch/testing repositories.

Comment: i am having the same problem and I guess it is because not all packages in testing are updated to 3.21.90. (e.g. `gnome-shell` is still 3.20.3).
So I hope this (and other issues) will solve itself in a few days. ([current status](https://www.0d.be/debian/debian-gnome-3.22-status.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display and brightness settings not working anymore is a bug introduced by a bad transition of GNOME (3.20 -> 3.21) from `sid` to `testing`.

**The bug will fix itself** once the transition is complete.

If you cannot wait for a couple of days, consider upgrading the packages which are still on 3.20 (upgrading the package `mutter` fixed the problem for some people). 
This is not recommended unless you know what you are doing.

Related bug reports:

[gnome-control-center could not get screen information anymore](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=836972)

[Screen brightness defaults to a very low value and can't be changed with Function Keys, Applet or in System Settings](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=836939)

Answer (score 1):

This Happened to me too. If you take a notice, that version of gnome is supposed to be for sid, not testing. Go and open terminal and you will see `gnome-shell --version` outputs the right version for testing. This is a version mismatch thus you can call it simply a weird bug.

Update `gnome-shell` from sid repository. Just add

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main 
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and invoke `apt-get update` after that.

As I do not know exactly which package is responsible for breaking the system I did update the following. `gnome-shell* gnome-shell-common`. After this the brightness control should work but the gnome-details still doesn't show the graphics card (some applications still will not work).

After that update `xserver-xorg-core`, that should totally fix the problem. Now you can remove SID lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list` to avoid fully upgrading to sid. Btw some gnome extensions will break as this is a `gnome-shell` upgrade. Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Upgrading gnome-shell to 3.21 from sid/unstable doesn't work for me as some of the packages even **in** sid/unstable report dependency problems, e.g.: `gnome-shell-pomodoro : Depends: gnome-shell (< 3.21) but 3.21.91-2 is to be installed`. At this moment, I fixed brightness control with shortcuts and don't really care for the info in details section so I'm fine with waiting a couple days for the problem to get resolved in the stretch/testing repository. Any suggestions or just wait it out?

Comment: As I did not have such a dependency problem, I am not sure what to recommend. If it is not a big deal for you then just wait I guess. I also couldn't start steam because of it apparently checks for the graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small update:
The package in testing [has been updated](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gnome-shell) and now everything works again (for me).